# Apache Solr client session time out exception, closing socket connection

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, session-timeout, solrcloud, solrclient

from few days i am getting below error in my apache solr cloud network.
but i am not exactly getting what the issue is my network is working fine all other thing is working properly also my machine is capable of bearing heavy load at solr cloud network still i faced below error due to which my shard and replica went dead and after sometime they started in recovery mode.
Also solr query response time increased very high when this error occur.
can anyone tell me what's issue is ?

Exact ERROR :
2023-08-30 09:55:22.381 WARN  (main-SendThread(10.10.10.10:44444)) [   ] o.a.z.ClientCnxn Session 0x299972fc6x1062c for sever 10.10.10.10/10.10.10.11:44444, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. => org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SessionTimeoutException: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 130773ms for session id 0x299972fc6x1062c
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1243)
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SessionTimeoutException: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 130773ms for session id 0x299972fc6x1062c
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1243) ~[?:?]